# Hiding other apps from mine - how to?

Tags: java, android, appsettings, android-package-managers, android-components

I want to make an application that can hide others, such as:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.apphider

I have this code, but it only works to hide my own app:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("pkg", "pkg.main");

p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

thanks for the help